# Oracle SQL - Return Data Ignoring Last 2 Characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to return a count of all stock in a database using a product number. I would also like to include the style names for that stock, however the stock comes in multiple sizes. ie,

```
Size Desc         SKU Desc      Quantity
20351779           Cool 1          10
20351779           Cool 1+         5
20351779           Cool 2          5
20351779           Cool 2+         10
20354807           Awkward 1       10
20354807           Awkward 1+      10
```

Unfortunately the style names are a variety of sizes so i can't substring them down, and if i do that it will still split the totals anyway.

What i'm looking for is something like this:-

```
Size Desc         SKU Desc      Quantity
20351779           Cool            30
20354807           Awkward         20
```

The code i have so far looks like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM
(select substr(SIZE_DESC,0,8), sum(actl_invn_Qty) as Bin, 
nvl(sum(actl_qty),0) as Crane, 
SUM(ACTL_INVN_QTY+nvl(ACTL_QTY,0)) As Total from item_master im
left outer join 
(Select cd.sku_id, SUM(cd.actl_qty) AS ACTL_QTY
FROM CASE_HDR CH
INNER JOIN CASE_DTL CD ON
CH.CASE_NBR = CD.CASE_NBR
INNER JOIN LOCN_HDR LH ON
CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID
WHERE CH.STAT_CODE = '30'
AND LH.AREA = '0'
AND LH.ZONE = 'Z'
GROUP BY CD.SKU_ID)tmp1 on im.sku_id = tmp1.sku_id
inner join (select pld.sku_id, SUM(pld.actl_invn_qty) AS ACTL_INVN_QTY
from pick_locn_dtl pld
GROUP BY PLD.SKU_ID)tmp2 on 
im.sku_id = tmp2.sku_id
where substr(im.size_desc,0,8) in 
('20351779',
'20354807')
GROUP BY substr(SIZE_DESC,0,8)
```

Is it possible to return the SKU Desc while ignoring the final two characters as they will always be the size on the SKU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
SELECT  
         SUBSTR ('MY STRING',
                 1,
                 LENGTH ('MY STRING') - INSTR (REVERSE ('MY STRING'), ' ', 1))
  FROM   DUAL;
```

The previous query removes all the part of the string at the right of the last space.

So, it returns 'MY'.

The following:

```
SELECT   
         SUBSTR ('MY FIRST STRING',
                 1,
                 LENGTH ('MY FIRST STRING') - INSTR (REVERSE ('MY FIRST STRING'), ' ', 1))
  FROM   DUAL;
```

returns 'MY FIRST'.

You have only to understand which part of your query:

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   (  SELECT   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8),
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS BIN,
                     NVL (SUM (ACTL_QTY), 0) AS CRANE,
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY + NVL (ACTL_QTY, 0)) AS TOTAL
              FROM         ITEM_MASTER IM
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                           (  SELECT   CD.SKU_ID, SUM (CD.ACTL_QTY) AS ACTL_QTY
                                FROM         CASE_HDR CH
                                          INNER JOIN
                                             CASE_DTL CD
                                          ON CH.CASE_NBR = CD.CASE_NBR
                                       INNER JOIN
                                          LOCN_HDR LH
                                       ON CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID
                               WHERE       CH.STAT_CODE = '30'
                                       AND LH.AREA = '0'
                                       AND LH.ZONE = 'Z'
                            GROUP BY   CD.SKU_ID) TMP1
                        ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP1.SKU_ID
                     INNER JOIN
                        (  SELECT   PLD.SKU_ID,
                                    SUM (PLD.ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS ACTL_INVN_QTY
                             FROM   PICK_LOCN_DTL PLD
                         GROUP BY   PLD.SKU_ID) TMP2
                     ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP2.SKU_ID
             WHERE   SUBSTR (IM.SIZE_DESC, 0, 8) IN ('20351779', '20354807')
          GROUP BY   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8));
```

represents 'MY STRING', and then you can use my formula.

From this:

```
SELECT   ALFA, BETA, GAMMA
  FROM   (  SELECT   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8),
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS BIN,
                     NVL (SUM (ACTL_QTY), 0) AS CRANE,
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY + NVL (ACTL_QTY, 0)) AS TOTAL
              FROM         ITEM_MASTER IM
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                           (  SELECT   CD.SKU_ID, SUM (CD.ACTL_QTY) AS ACTL_QTY
                                FROM         CASE_HDR CH
                                          INNER JOIN
                                             CASE_DTL CD
                                          ON CH.CASE_NBR = CD.CASE_NBR
                                       INNER JOIN
                                          LOCN_HDR LH
                                       ON CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID
                               WHERE       CH.STAT_CODE = '30'
                                       AND LH.AREA = '0'
                                       AND LH.ZONE = 'Z'
                            GROUP BY   CD.SKU_ID) TMP1
                        ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP1.SKU_ID
                     INNER JOIN
                        (  SELECT   PLD.SKU_ID,
                                    SUM (PLD.ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS ACTL_INVN_QTY
                             FROM   PICK_LOCN_DTL PLD
                         GROUP BY   PLD.SKU_ID) TMP2
                     ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP2.SKU_ID
             WHERE   SUBSTR (IM.SIZE_DESC, 0, 8) IN ('20351779', '20354807')
          GROUP BY   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8));
```

..... to this:

```
SELECT   ALFA,
         SUBSTR (BETA, 1, LENGTH (BETA) - INSTR (REVERSE (BETA), ' ', 1)),
         GAMMA
  FROM   (  SELECT   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8),
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS BIN,
                     NVL (SUM (ACTL_QTY), 0) AS CRANE,
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY + NVL (ACTL_QTY, 0)) AS TOTAL
              FROM         ITEM_MASTER IM
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                           (  SELECT   CD.SKU_ID, SUM (CD.ACTL_QTY) AS ACTL_QTY
                                FROM         CASE_HDR CH
                                          INNER JOIN
                                             CASE_DTL CD
                                          ON CH.CASE_NBR = CD.CASE_NBR
                                       INNER JOIN
                                          LOCN_HDR LH
                                       ON CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID
                               WHERE       CH.STAT_CODE = '30'
                                       AND LH.AREA = '0'
                                       AND LH.ZONE = 'Z'
                            GROUP BY   CD.SKU_ID) TMP1
                        ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP1.SKU_ID
                     INNER JOIN
                        (  SELECT   PLD.SKU_ID,
                                    SUM (PLD.ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS ACTL_INVN_QTY
                             FROM   PICK_LOCN_DTL PLD
                         GROUP BY   PLD.SKU_ID) TMP2
                     ON IM.SKU_ID = TMP2.SKU_ID
             WHERE   SUBSTR (IM.SIZE_DESC, 0, 8) IN ('20351779', '20354807')
          GROUP BY   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8));
```

Comment: Hi @UltraCommit thanks for the fast reply! This looks like exactly what i'm after, thank you! Couple questions though, is the
    FROM DUAL
part needed inside my code or is that just making it work seperately?
Also as for where to put it, the SKU Desc would normally sit after the second SELECT in my code, how would your part fit inside there? Thank you!!!

Comment: DUAL is a logical table Oracle predefined.  For example SELECT 1+1 FROM DUAL returns 2.  It's use to make select either directly other inside the code.  Your query begins with SELECT *.  Could you tell me what's the name of the fields?  SELECT ALFA, BETA, GAMMA instead of SELECT * ??

Comment: Please suppose that you have SELECT ALFA, BETA, GAMMA.  This means that, instead of BETA, you have to write: SUBSTR (BETA,
                 1,
                 LENGTH (BETA) - INSTR (REVERSE (BETA), ' ', 1))

Comment: This is because SKU DESC is the second field, it appears so.  I've named it BETA for example.

Comment: The SELECT * refers to the rest of the code, i have put the code you gave me inside 
SELECT   *
  FROM   (  SELECT   SUBSTR (SIZE_DESC, 0, 8),
                     SUBSTR (sku_desc,1,
                     LENGTH (sku_desc) - INSTR (REVERSE ('sku_desc'), ' ', 1)),

                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY) AS BIN,
                     NVL (SUM (ACTL_QTY), 0) AS CRANE,
                     SUM (ACTL_INVN_QTY + NVL (ACTL_QTY, 0)) AS TOTAL
              FROM         ITEM_MASTER IM

Comment: OK I hope it works.  I've passed you the formula, you can use it everywhere it needs.  It removes the part of the string at the right of the last space of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, one could use a regular expression to strip from the last space to the end of the line, inclusive.  This assumes your description ALWAYS has a size component following the last space that will be stripped:

```
select regexp_replace('Awkward 1', '(.*) [^$]+$', '\1') from dual;
```

Read it like this: regexp_replace(string to operate on, regular expression to match, replace string) where
regular expression to match means:

```
( Start a "remembered" group
. of any character
* and any number of any characters
) End the "remembered" group
  followed by a space character
[ Define a character class
^$ that matches any character that is NOT the end of the line character
] End the character class definition
+ Match multiple of the previous class
$ Match the end of the line
```

and the replace string is just the "remembered" part of the string (\1 stands for the 1st remembered group, there could be more), which is everything up to but not including the last space followed by anything until the end of the line.

EDIT:
Actually, this may be simpler:

```
select regexp_replace('Awkward test 1', ' [^$| ]+$', '') from dual;
```

Search for  a space followed any character that is NOT the end of the line or NOT a space until the end of the line is found.  Replace with nothing.

Comment: I think i can understand how this works @gary, thanks. Could you then in theory use something along these lines to strip any character from a selection?

Comment: Yes, as long as it can be described by the regular expression.